Decrease font at the top of the VS Code window
How can I decrease the font size at the top of the VS Code window (red, 1st picture) on Ubuntu? I can use the standard Ctrl + + or - to change the size of the content (green, 1st picture), but that does not affect the header, nor the right-click dropdown menu size (red, 2nd picture). I am wondering whether that is even a VS Code option, or whether I would need to adjust Ubuntu system settings.
Thanks!



That font size (titlbar and context menu) is controlled by Ubuntu, actually. You might want to try Tweaks app and try to change the font and font size there, and see it is changes that.
But this will have a side effect on every system text.
Install GNOME Tweaks using this apt command
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks 


Yeah, thats what I thought too! I tried that already, but none of these options here seem to affect the fonts I am interested in. https://imgur.com/a/X8WOR9M
Do you know which setting I need to touch? :)

That didn't work? Did you try interface and legacy window title fonts?

In that case, try this command to set a value higher than 1
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor <value>
